# Sturges only wants to trade in Molecular mission?

Tags: fallout-4

In the molecular level mission, I have to talk to Sturges to use the teleporter, but when I speak to him he only wants to trade.

I'm supposed to be able to ask him to use the teleported, but he just wants to trade.

How can I fix this glitch?

Comment: have you retaken the castle for the Minutemen yet?

Comment: Did he tell you to get on the platform yet? Did you try getting on the platform?

Answer (score 3):

### You might be experiencing a known Sturges bug that limits his interaction to trade.

[There is a known bug with Sturges, which is most commonly encountered during The Molecular Level](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Molecular_Level#Bugs), and sounds similar to what you report;

> - If the Commonwealth Minutemen faction was chosen to assist, upon returning from The Institute, it will no longer be possible to assign a task to Sturges, nor relocate him, via the workshop menu. He will no longer require, or use, a bed, nor will he count towards the population of Sanctuary Hills. It is still possible to trade items with him, however. <sup>**[verified]**</sup>

[and in a similar case](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sturges#Bugs), which specifically occurs after completing The Molecular Level:

> - After the The Molecular Level is complete, Sturges will be non-assignable, and if the teleporter is built in another place, he will automatically teleport to Sanctuary Hills. <sup>**[verified]**</sup>

---

### Confirming the bug

You can further confirm this reported bug by testing the other issues that arise:

- Can you assign a task to Sturges?
- Can you relocate Sturges, through the workshop menu?

### Possible Solutions

There have been several reported solutions to the bug, but unfortunately, the most reliable use console commands and can only be performed on computer.

#### Xbox One / PlayStation 4 Solutions

If you are on Xbox One or PlayStation 4, you do not have access to the console, but you can still try resetting the cell. Fast travel to a location that is suitably far from Sanctuary Hills, such as Railroad HQ or Salem. Sleep for 15 days, for good measure.

This might work **some** of the time, but if no other solution can be found, you might have to consider [resetting the quest point](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Molecular_Level#Notes) or reverting to an earlier save file.

#### Computer

If you have access to the console, you are in for a better chance. There are several options you can take, to attempt to reset Sturges.

Just to be safe:
 - Make a separate save before any console manipulation, just in case you lose Sturges, or have any other unforeseen issues.
 - Ensure you are actually in Sanctuary Hills, to limit issues such as losing Sturges.
 - If the console solutions do not appear to work, confirm that they have still taken some form of effect, and perform the reset method listed under console. There are some reports that various solutions will not "ripple through" immediately.

**Manually set Sturges to 'commandable'**

One of the major issues this bug causes is the inability to actually command Sturges, as a settler. In some cases, solving this issue appears to also solve the related problems.

- `prid 0001a4d8, moveto player` to select Sturges, and move him to your current position.
- `setpv bcommandable 1` to manually set Sturges to a commandable NPC.

**Manually reset Sturges**

You can try resetting the NPC object that represents Sturges. Keep in mind that this command is intended for non-essential NPCs, and might result in some unexpected behavior.

- `prid 0001a4d8, recycleactor` to reset Sturges, as an NPC object.

**Phoenix-reset Sturges**

If all else fails, you can try killing and resurrecting Sturges. Keep in mind that this is only a last-resort solution, and is offered only as a means to attempt to further trick your computer into jumping ahead of the bugged road block.

You might also want to perform a regular reset, perhaps both before and after Sturges is dead, and again, after you resurrect him. I can not stress this enough, **make a separate save of your game before you do this**. You could skip yourself out of a messy hole, you could dig the messy hold deeper.

- `setessential 0001a4d8 0` to mark Sturges as a non-essential NPC.
- `prid 0001a4d8` to select Sturges.
- `targetID.kill` to kill your selected target, currently Sturges.
- `targetID.resurrect` to resurrect your selected target, currently Sturges.
- `setessential 0001a4d8 1` to change Sturges back to an essential NPC.

Lastly, be aware that we are using the console to kill Sturges, as resurrecting him will not fix visual injury such as crippled limbs or missing heads. If you feel like taking advantage of the situation to punish Sturges with a bit more violence, you can fix any visual injuries by disabling and re-enabling the NPC object:

- `prid 0001a4d8` to select Sturges.
- `disable` to disable the selected object, currently Sturges.
- `enable` to enable the selected object, currently Sturges.

Comment: +1, looks good. What do you think the odds are of the asker actually coming back and seeing it?

Comment: @DCShannon, unlikely, based on the askers "last seen" time stamp I'd say they  never came back to check on the question in the first place. But it seems this bug comes up for quite a few people, so perhaps it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any game saved at that point to test... But here's what I can think of :

- Did you build all teleporter component? (4 if I remember correctly)
- Are they all linked together? (Powerline linked, not sure if it's required, but mine were when I did the quest)
- Do you have enough power for it? (It takes a lot of power... 30 power unit if I remember correctly).